# Sails application cannot accessed from web browser. Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, docker, sails.js, docker-compose, sails-mongo

I am trying to develop a sails application that uses mongodb which works under docker.
Steps that I followed is given below.

1. Cloned application which contains mongodb connections from our git repository.
2. Built it using following command
    **docker build -t bit .**
3. Executed docker-compose up 
    **docker-compose up -d**
4. Tried to get port of the docker container using
    **docker ps**
5. Run the application using
    **docker run -d -p 8083:27108 sample**

Tried to access application using

http://localhost:8083 - shows connection refused

http://localhost:27018 - shows It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

**We are trying to make this sails application portable using docker. Means, this application could be run on any system with docker installed.**

Comment: Can you post your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Moreover step 5. is not running the application. As you have it now, it's running a container deriving from the image `sample`, Post your `docker-compose.yml` and the output of the command `docker ps`